# How does Xpath/XML assertions use more resources?

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter

I read in a blog post that xpath/xml assertion use more memory, so we should avoid using them.

Could anyone please explain to me how they are using more resources than other assertions?

Comment: If you shared a link to the blog post, it would be easier to identify the details of this claim from the context. One of the biggest details is, "more than what kind of other assertions?"

Answer (score 1):

Xml\XPath is inherently more CPU/memory intensive than a simple integer/numeric/string assertion, just through the fact that the XML must be parsed.

As with all these things the real answer to whether it will be a problem for you is 'it depends' and you should profile and test to see.

Answer (score 0):

XPath Assertion or XPath Extractor build DOM tree of the response in memory hence **each** thread consumes as much memory as response body. Here is how memory being used.

Traversing DOM tree and XPath evaluating expressions is a CPU intensive process.

So if you can avoid using XPath assertion - it would be good. If not - make sure that JMeter has enough heap to have a lot of response body objects in memory.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more detailed explanations and recommendations.